# No Primary key error when i put ManyToOne annotation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence

I have this hierarchy

```
T1(
   id (pk),
   name (varchar)
)

T2(
  id (pk),
  t1_id (fk_t1),
  number (int)
)

T3 (
  id (pk),
  t2_id (fk_t2),
  time (datetime)
  zone (tinyint),
  name (varchar)
)
```

and this is my `T3Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T3, schema="", catalog="dbname")
public class T3Entity{
    private int id;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private int zone;
    private String name;

   @Id
   @Column(name="id", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="datetime", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="zone", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="name", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

}
```

When I added this code in `T3Entity` class, I got an error

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumn(name="T2_id", referencedColumn="T2_id")
private T2Entity t2Entity;
//getters-setters
```

I got this error

```
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [PU] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7161] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Entity class [class com.project.entity.T3Entity] has no primary key specified. It should define either an @Id, @EmbeddedId or an @IdClass. If you have defined PK using any of these annotations then make sure that you do not have mixed access-type (both fields and properties annotated) in your entity class hierarchy.
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be

```
@JoinColumn(name="T2_id")
```

instead of

```
@JoinColumn(name="T2_id", referencedColumn="T2_id")
```

I don't know about EclipseLink, but Hibernate won't even let me specify a non-existant column name as the `referencedColumn`. If you insist, it should be

```
@JoinColumn(name="T2_id", referencedColumn="id")
```

so that it references a column that exists.